# Maven Surefire report is overwriting previous report

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Every time i'm executing my tests using maven it write the results over the previous results... 
is there a way to generate the outputs on a folder with timestamp? or any other solution?

Comment: Are doing this locally or on a CI solution like jenkins?

Comment: Locally, but i don't think it will be different on CI

Comment: Why do need the difference? What is the purpose of that? The results will be created for the current run ? Some kind of history overview?

Answer (score 0):

You can personalize the report name in your plugin configuration:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.20</version>
        <configuration>
          <outputName>desired_name</outputName>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  [...]
</project>
```

You can then concatenate a name with the timestamp in your pom: `${maven.build.timestamp}`

Taken from [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/changing-report-name.html).

Additionally, you can also specify the output folder of your report. It is all there in the [plugin documentation page](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html).

Comment: I'll check it, thansk